# Regex all character after first position in Dart

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I'm trying to achieve this `J*** D**` from `John Doe` string but my current code output is `**** ***`.
Here is my current code:

```
void main() {
  String txt = 'John Doe';
  String hideStr = txt.replaceAll(RegExp(r'\S'), '*');
  print(hideStr);
}
```

any suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use negative look behind to exclude the character at start and after white-space

```
void main() {
    String txt = 'John Doe';
    String hideStr = txt.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<!^|\s)[^\s]'), '*');
    print(hideStr);
}
```

Because "J" and "D" sit after start of text and a space, the regex won't match it

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```dart
String hideStr = txt.replaceAll(RegExp(r'(?<=\S)\S'), '*');
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FLu3Ja/1). *Details*:

- `(?<=\S)` - a non-whitespace char is required immediately before the current location
- `\S`  - a whitespace char.

A non-lookbehind solution is also possible:

```dart
String hideStr = txt.replaceAllMapped(RegExp(r'(\S)(\S*)'), 
    (Match m) => "${m[1]}${'*' * (m[2]?.length ?? 0)}");
```

*Details*:

- `(\S)(\S*)` regex matches and captures into Group 1 a non-whitespace char, and then zero or more whitespace chars are captured into Group 2
- `${m[1]}${'*' * (m[2]?.length ?? 0)}` replacement is a concatenation of

  - `${m[1]}` - Group 1 value
  - `${'*' * (m[2]?.length ?? 0)}` - a `*` char repeated the time of Group 2 length. `?? 0` is necessary since `m[2]?.length` returns a nullable int).